# Enable https in NodeJS using rejoice

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am having nodejs microservice built on HapiJS. For starting the server we use rejoice which uses .json file for configuration.
    `"server": {
    },
    "connections": [
        {
            "port": 5000,
            "host": "0.0.0.0"
        }
    ]`

Above port configuration been picked when we are staring the sever using rejoice command. Now we are try to run the nodejs service using https, i am not able to find out how can i do that. I see the hapi docs which says passing tls object as part of connections parameter will be send as it is nodejs. Refer [Hapi server options](https://hapi.dev/api/?v=16.8.1#serverconnectionoptions) . Now i tried passing tls object inside the connections array

```
"connections": [
    {
        "port": 5000,
        "host": "0.0.0.0"
        "tls" :{
            "cert":"./server_certificate.pem",
            "key": "./server_key.pem"               
         }
    }
]
```

then getting below.

```
Problems while parsing the config_prod.json file. Make sure the file exists and is well formatted. 
Error: Unexpected string in JSON at position 116
./change_request/node_modules/glue/node_modules/joi/lib/index.js:144
throw error;
ValidationError: Invalid manifest "value" must be an object
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a valid json as you are missing a comma after host. It should be

```
"connections": [
    {
        "port": 5000,
        "host": "0.0.0.0",
        "tls" :{
            "cert":"./server_certificate.pem",
            "key": "./server_key.pem"               
         }
    }
]
```